# Sending Input Type Text Value to Another File Using href in PHP (pure php solution)

Tags: php

I have an input type text box as follows

```
<input type="text" name="deleteprofileconfirmation" id="deleteprofileconfirmation" class="editprofileinput">
<a href="../controllers/deleteaccount.php" class="deleteprofilebutton" name="deleteprofilebutton" id="deleteprofilebutton">Delete Account</a>
```

I need to pass the value entered in the input type text to deleteaccount.php

I can do with help of jquery, no problem, i need a pure php solution...

I tried using sessions, but problem is how to read the value in input type when link is clicked.. $_POST is also not working...

i cannot use form because this is a form in another form so html5 is not allowing nested forms, sorry should have mentioned that earlier

the following is not working on deleteaccount.php

```
if (isset($_POST['deleteprofilebutton']))
{
    $delete_profile = strtolower($_POST['deleteprofileconfirmation']);
}
```

Comment: try to add within form tag

Comment: i cannot use form because this is a form in another form so html5 is not allowing nested forms, sorry should have mentioned that earlier

Comment: pass with URL deleteaccount.php?KEY=VALUE

Comment: please show me how

Comment: You can use submit button with another name

Answer (score 0):

Make your link as

```
href="../controllers/deleteaccount.php?id=$ID_VALUE"
```

and update the `POST` to `GET`

```
if (isset($_GET['id']))
{
   $delete_profile = strtolower($_GET['id']);
}
```

That would be `GET` now.

Make sure users with no privileges can hit this url and delete the profiles. Do check the user rights before processing the delete operation.

Comment: how is $ID_VALUE going to get the value from <input type="text" name="deleteprofileconfirmation"> for example if some enetered thank you in the textbox, can we see this value "thank you" in deleteaccount.php

Comment: what do you need to do exactly? you want id and text value as well?

Comment: i need to pass whatevered entered in  <input type="text" name="deleteprofileconfirmation"> to be passed to deleteaccount.php when the link is clicked

Comment: don't need the value of ID?

Comment: create a form, create a hidden field. onClick event, call a js function, fill the hidden field with that text field value and submit form...

Comment: cannot use form (nested form problem in html5), cannot use javascript... (already have solution but need in pure php)

Comment: I am not asking you to create a form inside a form, create form anywhere on the page on the button or top with a hidden field... submit that form using FORMSUBMIT() of query and fill the hidden field value with this text field value before submission...getting it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using form

```
 <form action="../controllers/deleteaccount.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="deleteprofileconfirmation" id="deleteprofileconfirmation" class="editprofileinput">
    <input type="submit" class="deleteprofilebutton" name="deleteprofilebutton" id="deleteprofilebutton" value="Delete Account">
    </form>
```

Comment: cannot use form, must use ahref

Comment: no i already have a solution with ajax.. but i need pure php solution

Comment: when type  text is writing down on this text you can dynamically create anchor(a) tag href link using jquery.  like that "../controllers/deleteaccount.php?text =value "

Comment: i need pure php solution

Comment: Sorry to say that It isn't possible to do this with pure PHP. You must have to use browser script like javascript.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136926/discussion-between-mithu-cn-and-dragonfire).

Answer (score 0):

You could also give each one a unique name and just check the $_POST for the existence of that input.

```
<input type="submit" name="deleteprofileconfirmation" value="Delete" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
```

And in the code:

```
if (isset($_POST['deleteprofileconfirmation'])) {
    //delete action
} else if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    //submit action
} else {
    //no button pressed
}
```

Comment: without form how can you post data ?

Comment: He is already using form.., So his doubt is how can use two submit buttons in single form.